# Errors description guideline

Tags: language-agnostic, error-handling

Is there any guideline to classify and describe errors that a program throws? I'm talking about errors that I define in the code.

I've read that error description should be as specific as possible, but I was looking for some more rigid guideline of good practices on the topic.

Any hint apprecciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Guideline? Try to have as few errors as possible....Define exceptions for exceptional circumstances

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, not properly program/script errors, I meant if something went wrong how to display that in a more "universal" way, obviously with a graceful exit first

Comment: make sure you log errors: users are not that interested in the details, only that the app. works!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is marked with "language-agnostic", but it depends a lot on the langauge that you are using in that you should follow the patterns and practices most commonly used in that language (and therefore most familiar to developers).

For example, read [Error Raising and Handling Guidelines (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ey5ey87%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for some Microsoft .Net exception handling guidelines. (which I've just noticed are actually out of date, for example it recommends inheriting from `ApplicationException`).